# Calculate percentage while select - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, percentage

I have a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetReportData
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        LOC.SubCompanyNameVN,
        LOC.BranchName,
        COUNT(LOC.BranchCode) as Total,

        ----------- Not Processed Yet
        -- Count
        (SELECT COUNT(WS.ID)
            FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS WS
            JOIN DBO.Location AS LO ON WS.LocationID = LO.LocationID AND WS.BranchCode = LO.BranchCode
            WHERE WS.Status = 5 OR WS.Status = 6 AND LO.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode) AS CountNotProcessedYet,
        ------------

        ----------- Processing
        -- Count
        (SELECT COUNT(WS.ID)
            FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS WS
            JOIN DBO.Location AS LO ON WS.LocationID = LO.LocationID AND WS.BranchCode = LO.BranchCode
            WHERE WS.Status = 3 AND LO.BranchName = LOC.BranchName) AS CountProcessing,
        ------------
    FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS SS
    JOIN DBO.Location AS LOC ON SS.LocationID = LOC.LocationID AND SS.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode
    JOIN DBO.Status AS ST ON SS.Status = ST.ID
    GROUP BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN, LOC.BranchName, LOC.BranchCode
    ORDER BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN
END
```

Result:

| SubCompanyNameVN | BranchName | Total | CountNotProcessedYet | CountProcessing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vùng 1 | HNI_01 | 5 | 3 | 2 |
| Vùng 1 | HNI_02 | 15 | 5 | 10 |
| Vùng 1 | HNI_07 | 12 | 6 | 6 |

But my expect result is:

| SubCompanyNameVN | BranchName | Total | CountNotProcessedYet | percentNotProcessedYet | CountProcessing | percentProcessing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vùng 1 | HNI_01 | 5 | 3 | 60% | 2 | 40% |
| Vùng 1 | HNI_02 | 15 | 5 | 33.33% | 10 | 66.67% |
| Vùng 1 | HNI_07 | 12 | 6 | 50% | 6 | 50% |

So I update my stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetReportData
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        LOC.SubCompanyNameVN,
        LOC.BranchName,
        COUNT(LOC.BranchCode) as Total,

        ----------- Not Processed Yet
        -- Count
        (SELECT COUNT(WS.ID)
            FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS WS
            JOIN DBO.Location AS LO ON WS.LocationID = LO.LocationID AND WS.BranchCode = LO.BranchCode
            WHERE WS.Status = 5 OR WS.Status = 6 AND LO.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode) AS CountNotProcessedYet,
         --- Percent
        ROUND((CountNotProcessedYet/Total)*100,2)
        ------------

        ----------- Processing
        -- Count
        (SELECT COUNT(WS.ID)
            FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS WS
            JOIN DBO.Location AS LO ON WS.LocationID = LO.LocationID AND WS.BranchCode = LO.BranchCode
            WHERE WS.Status = 3 AND LO.BranchName = LOC.BranchName) AS CountProcessing,
        --- Percent
        ROUND((CountProcessing/Total)*100,2)
        ------------
    FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS SS
    JOIN DBO.Location AS LOC ON SS.LocationID = LOC.LocationID AND SS.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode
    JOIN DBO.Status AS ST ON SS.Status = ST.ID
    GROUP BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN, LOC.BranchName, LOC.BranchCode
    ORDER BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN
END
```

Error:

[image]

Is there any way I can calculate the percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly on the error message you are getting, you can't reference to the column alias like that on the same level.

```
CountProcessing/Total
```

You can either use a `CTE` or derived query to calculate `Total` and `CountProcessing` and then calculate the `Percent` on the outer query using the column alias.

You can simplified your query using `CASE` expression instead of sub-query

```
SELECT
    LOC.SubCompanyNameVN,
    LOC.BranchName,
    COUNT(LOC.BranchCode) as [Total],
    SUM (CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (5,6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [CountNotProcessedYet],
    SUM (CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (3)   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [CountProcessing],
    ROUND (SUM (CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (3)   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(LOC.BranchCode), 2) as [Percent]
FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS SS
JOIN DBO.Location AS LOC ON SS.LocationID = LOC.LocationID AND SS.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode
JOIN DBO.Status AS ST ON SS.Status = ST.ID
GROUP BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN, LOC.BranchName
ORDER BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not nickname a column and use the same name for a computational column at the same time in one step of the process. Change your query as shown below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetReportData
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT
    SubCompanyNameVN,
    BranchName,
    Total,
    CountNotProcessedYet,
    ROUND((CountNotProcessedYet/Total)*100,2),
    CountProcessing,
    ROUND((CountProcessing/Total)*100,2)
  FROM
    (SELECT 
        LOC.SubCompanyNameVN,
        LOC.BranchName,
        COUNT(LOC.BranchCode) as Total,

        ----------- Not Processed Yet
        -- Count
        (SELECT COUNT(WS.ID)
            FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS WS
            JOIN DBO.Location AS LO ON WS.LocationID = LO.LocationID AND WS.BranchCode = LO.BranchCode
            WHERE WS.Status = 5 OR WS.Status = 6 AND LO.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode) AS CountNotProcessedYet,
        ----------- Processing
        -- Count
        (SELECT COUNT(WS.ID)
            FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS WS
            JOIN DBO.Location AS LO ON WS.LocationID = LO.LocationID AND WS.BranchCode = LO.BranchCode
            WHERE WS.Status = 3 AND LO.BranchName = LOC.BranchName) AS CountProcessing,
       
    FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS SS
    JOIN DBO.Location AS LOC ON SS.LocationID = LOC.LocationID AND SS.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode
    JOIN DBO.Status AS ST ON SS.Status = ST.ID
    GROUP BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN, LOC.BranchName, LOC.BranchCode) T
  ORDER BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this

```
    SELECT 
        LOC.SubCompanyNameVN,
        LOC.BranchName,
        COUNT(SS.ID) as Total,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (5, 6)
              THEN SS.ID END) AS CountNotProcessedYet, 
        ROUND((COUNT(CASE WHEN SS.Status IN (5, 6)
              THEN SS.ID END)/COUNT(SS.ID))*100,2) AS PercentNotProcessedYet, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN SS.Status = 3
              THEN SS.ID END) AS CountProcessing, 
        ROUND((COUNT(CASE WHEN SS.Status = 3
              THEN SS.ID END)/COUNT(SS.ID))*100,2) AS PercentProcessing
    FROM DBO.WorkingSession AS SS
    JOIN DBO.Location AS LOC ON SS.LocationID = LOC.LocationID AND SS.BranchCode = LOC.BranchCode
    JOIN DBO.Status AS ST ON SS.Status = ST.ID
    GROUP BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN, LOC.BranchName, LOC.BranchCode
    ORDER BY LOC.SubCompanyNameVN
```